Python packaging: including files/modules which import each other
Sorry for the simple question, but I've been through some tutorials and I'm still not sure what the best way is to solve my issue.
I'm trying to install my Python code locally to make it easier to import into other projects I'm developing (the core project is a simulator which I want to utilise in other applications).
I have the following package structure:
simulator/
+- simulator/
   +- data/
      +- model.yaml
   +- __init__.py
   +- sim.py
   +- dynamics.py
   +- config.py
+- setup.py

with this setup.py file:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='simulator',
      version='0.1.0',
      author='LC',
      packages=find_packages(include=['simulator', 'simulator.*'])
)

Running pip install -e . --user in the top-level simulator folder achieves the desired result of installing the package, e.g. I am able to use the statements
import simulator
from simulator.sim import run

from other code files on my system. But, say that sim imports dynamics. This breaks things - I get a ModuleNotFoundError when the second statement is run.
What do I need to do to package the code when the files/modules within the package import each other in this way? I suppose I could import them all inside __init__.py, as in this article: https://changhsinlee.com/python-package/, but I don't know if this will cause some circular import issues, or other unintended consequences.
(As an aside, how can I ensure the data folder and yaml file are included too?)

You've got one package, so take 'simulator.*' out of the package spec. sim could import simulator.dynamics - using the full package name. Or it could from .dynamics import foo, bar - that's a package relative import.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/what-happens-when-using-mutual-or-circular-cyclic-imports , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+circular+import

@tdelaney Using absolute imports did the trick. Thank you.
